# Generate a property name in a loop

Tags: vb.net, properties, insertonsubmit

I'm trying to find a way of loading a single record with 25 columns into a datatable.

I could list all 25 variables called `SPOT1` to `SPOT25` (columns in the datatable) but I'm looking for more concise method like using a loop or dictionary.

The code below shows two methods, a 'long' method which is cumbersome, and a 'concise' method which I'm trying to get help with.

```
Public dctMC As Dictionary(Of String, VariantType)
Dim newMC As New MONTE_CARLO()

'long method: this will work but is cumbersome
newMC.SPOT1=999
newMC.SPOT2=887
...
newMC.SPOT25=5

'concise method:  can it be done more concisely, like in a loop for example?
 Dim k As String

For x = 1 To 25
    k = "SPOT" & CStr(x)
    newMC.K = dctMC(k)    'convert newMC.k to newMC.SPOT1 etc
Next

'load record
DATA.MONTE_CARLOs.InsertOnSubmit(newMC)
```

Comment: rather than ask for help with your perceived solution, please describe the actual problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: As @MitchWheat suggests, there is probably a better way to reach your goal than the way your are currently trying. One possibility might be to for `MONTE_CARLO` to have a `Spot` property that returns an array or collection than can hold the 25 different values.

Comment: @Mitch...tks for the feedback...I've edited the question and I hope this is clearer.

Comment: @Blackwood...that sounds like it might work, please can you send me some more detail?

Comment: It would really be better for you to describe what you are trying to do. It seems quite unusual and there may well be a better way of doing it.

Comment: Sorry I thought I had. I'm trying to insert a record with 25 columns (ultimately there will be 250 columns) into a datatable. I could list each column with its value as show in the code, but I'd like to find a more concise way of doing this since the column names are similar and there are so many of them.

Comment: Just so you know, the the `DataRow` object has an `ItemArray` property, which will allow you to set the fields in a loop.You need to be sure of the column order, though. Or you could use a loop to go through the column names e.g. `myDataRow("Spot" & x.ToString)=555`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the others, I think there are better solutions, but it is possible...

```
Public Class MONTE_CARLO
  Private mintSpot(-1) As Integer
  Property Spot(index As Integer) As Integer
    Get
      If index > mintSpot.GetUpperBound(0) Then
        ReDim Preserve mintSpot(index)
      End If
      Return mintSpot(index)
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
      If index > mintSpot.GetUpperBound(0) Then
        ReDim Preserve mintSpot(index)
      End If
      mintSpot(index) = value
    End Set
  End Property
End Class
```

Usage...

```
Dim newMC As New MONTE_CARLO
For i As Integer = 0 To 100
  newMC.Spot(i) = i
Next i
MsgBox(newMC.Spot(20))
```

Comment: thanks SSS, that's what I'm looking for. One simple question (I've never used a property before) how do I set a value for say spot(20)? Just call ``spot(20)=555`` from a function?

Comment: Yes that's correct `newMC.Spot(20)=555` will set the property. Inside the `Property Set` code, `index` will be set to 20, and `value` will be set to 555. The underlying storage of the data is in the array `mintSpot()`, which is out-of-scope (i.e. hidden) for the calling code.

Comment: tks for all your help!

Comment: SSS, I've just looked your comment again - I'm not committed to using a loop, can you suggest a better method? All I'd like is a simple, concise method to load a record containing many columns. I also prefer to use dictionaries.

Comment: Are you loading from the database, or writing to the database, or something else?

Comment: SSS this was getting too complex for my current understanding of vb.net and accessing databases. So to keep the project rolling I've simplified the datatable and used the 'longer' method. But thanks for all the advice it has really helped and I'll get back to this down the track.

Comment: No worries, happy programming!